# How do I dereference a pointer that is an element of an array that is passed into a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

So I am working on a homework assignment that requires us to take an integer array and create a parallel array of pointers that will then point to the corresponding element in the original array. We are then to sort the array of pointers into numerical order, and use a bubble sort in a function to do so. My question is, once the array of pointers is passed to the function, how do I dereference back to the value that the element pointer points to so that i can use comparisons in the bubble sort, switch values, and output the sorted arrays? Am i right to pass the array of pointers into a pointer, or should I pass the actual array into the function? Code as it is currently below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *[], int);
void swapvalues(int *, int *);


int main()
{
    int dataarray[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 123, 124, 125, 3000, 3000, 82, 876, 986, 345, 1990, 2367, 98, 2, 444, 993, 635, 283, 544, 923, 18, 543, 777, 234, 549, 864, 39, 97, 986, 986, 1, 2999, 473, 776, 9, 23, 397, 15, 822, 1927, 1438, 1937, 1956, 7, 29, -1 };
    int *ptrarray[100];
    int flag1 = 0;
    int flag2 = 0;
    int flag3 = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    const int size = sizeof(dataarray) / sizeof(int);
    for (i; i <= size; i++)
    {
        ptrarray[i] = &dataarray[i];
    }
    sort(ptrarray, size);




    return 0;
}


void sort(int ptrarray[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    for (i; i < size; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        for (j; j < (size-1); j++)
        {
            if ((*(ptrarray + j)) == (*(ptrarray + (j + 1))))
            {
                swapvalues(ptrarray, j);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
}

void swapvalues(int *ptrarray, int j)
{
    int holder;
    holder = *(ptrarray + j);
    *(ptrarray + j) = *(ptrarray + (j + 1));
    *(ptrarray + (j + 1)) = holder;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way.

Comment: downvote: you asked this question because you didn't listen to a single word of your CS lectures.

Comment: What's the purpose of `ptrarray` ? Just call your `sort` function directly on `dataarray`.

Comment: The assignment says we are supposed to leave dataarray untouched and make an array of pointers that point to dataarray to be sorted.

Comment: And I do listen, sir, the explanation of this topic just left a lot to be desired.

Comment: @RussellDavis  Did you even compile it ?

Comment: Not yet since the logic I'm using is unworkable/won't compile.

Comment: @RussellDavis  What exactly is your question? Title  is  bit confusing.

Comment: `for (j; j < (size-1); j)` what is this supposed to *do* ?

Comment: If it won't even compile then asking how to solve the problem is getting ahead of yourself. Get what you have to compile first then ask how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just pass the array in, not a pointer to it as C will not actually copy the array it will use a pointer to it anyway. Then, to dereference the pointers you could use *(ptrarray[j]) where j iterates from 0 to the size of the array. It would also be valid to do **(ptrarray+j), which would first dereference the array pointer to get the element pointed at, and then dereference that element to get the original value.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think thats correct. In the statement *(ptrarray+j) the array pointer is dereferenced, but the pointer that's stored there is not. Also, the poster wasn't asking what was wrong with his code involving the for loop, he just wanted to know how to dereference the array correctly.

Comment: That's still wrong. *(ptrarray[j]) does not equal *(ptrarry+j). One performs one dereference, the other performs two...

Comment: I updated my code, and tried implementing what you suggested, but it did not appear to work, as the program does basically nothing (the array of pointers does not sort).

Comment: Something that seems somewhat confusing about your original solution is the line if ((*(ptrarray + j)) == (*(ptrarray + (j + 1)))). If you wanted it to sort, I think you would need to be doing some kind of > or < comparison, not checking to see if they are equal. Swapping two equivalent values will not actually change the array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this code will not compile as you function `sort` -

```
 void sort(int *[], int);
               ^array of pointers 


void sort(int *ptrarray, int size)
              ^pointer
```

So compiler will give error.

Declare function as -

```
void sort(int **ptrarray, int size)
```

And also increment `j` in this for loop-

```
 for (j; j < (size-1); j)
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call this:

```
void sort(int ptrarray[], int size)
```

With this:

```
int *ptrarray[100];
sort(ptrarray, size);
```

As sort is expecting an array of `int`, while you're passing it an array of `int *`.  `sort` should be declared as:

```
void sort(int *ptrarray[], int size)
```

Also, this:

```
if ((*(ptrarray + j)) == (*(ptrarray + (j + 1))))
```

Is comparing the pointers themselves, not the values they point to, which is what you really want to compare, and it's not the right comparison.  You instead want this:

```
if (*(ptrarray[j]) > *(ptrarray[j + 1]))
```

I'd recommend sticking with the `a[i]` syntax rather than the `*(a + i)` syntax as it's more clear.

Your swap function should also change to take pointers to two ints:

```
void swapvalues(int *a, int *b)
{
    int holder;
    holder = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = holder;
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
swapvalues(ptrarray[j], ptrarray[j+1]);
```

Your loop initialization is also off.  Here's the full `sort` function:

```
void sort(int *ptrarray[], int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < (size-1); j++)
        {
            if (*(ptrarray[j]) > *(ptrarray[j + 1]))
            {
                swapvalues(ptrarray[j], ptrarray[j+1]);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
}
```